# When $.proxy or myFunc.bind don't work for correcting reference to 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, this

I thought I'd got my head around context and scope in javascript. I don't understand why in one situation proxy/bind works, and in another it doesn't. Please could someone explain?

Example 1: Proxy (or bind) works:

```
function Cat(name){
    this.name = name;

    $("#cat").click(
        $.proxy(
            function(e){ this.meow(e); }
        , this)
    );

    this.meow = function(){ alert(this.name + "says meow"); }
}
var cat = new Cat();
```

Example 2: Proxy and bind don't work:

```
function Dog(breed){
    this.breed = breed;

    this.save = function(){
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/savedog.php', dataType: 'json',

            // This works?? Shouldn't scope be of .ajax()?
            data: this.breed, 

            // success: $.proxy(... // won't work? why?
            success: that.dogSaved, error: ajaxFail
        });
    };

    this.dogSaved = function(){ alert("Dog Saved"); }
}
var dog = new Dog();
```

Comment: You forgot to wrap your code in `function(){}` for your second click handler.

Comment: The update to your question leaves your situation unclear.  You say that using `$.proxy` in some unspecified way doesn't work, but you don't say how exactly you use it and you don't say how exactly it doesn't work.

Comment: I *did* answer your question properly in its original incarnation.  The change you made is significant, as it removed an obvious problem. Without that, all that's left is your vague statement about something not working - something you describe with "...".

Comment: Answer updated with a guess at what the issue might be.

Comment: My question was as precise as it could be, hence my request for an encompasing explanation rather than a specific solution; I already have the solution, but I am after an understanding of the difference between the scenarios that necessitates different solutions

Comment: Well, it would have been more precise had you shown the details of how you used `$.proxy()` in the situation that didn't work out. I mean, since you were left in a state of confusion, there must have been some actual code that you tried.  It would be helpful to see exactly what it looked like.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer. The code that didn't work was: success: $.proxy(this.dog, this),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying `this` to `that` *inside* the "click" handler.  Do it outside.

The value of `this` is set anew for and upon each function call.  Thus, inside your "click" handler, `this` is not a dog, it's a DOM element.

It's also important to be mindful of the order of evaluation in JavaScript.  Parameters to functions are fully evaluated in the context of the *calling* environment.  In your first example, the value of `this` passed in to `$.proxy()` is the correct one because it's a parameter in the context of the `Cat` constructor, and thus it is correctly a cat.  In your call to `$.ajax` in the `Dog` constructor, however, the reference to `this.breed` will not have the correct value, as it is evaluated in the context of the "click" handler and *not* the constructor.  The value of the "data" property should be `that.breed` once you've fixed the initialization of `that` as described above.

(Also note that as @Musa points out, the `Dog` constructor is syntactically incorrect; I assume that was just a transcription error.)

*edit* — I'm not sure what you're trying with `$.proxy()` in your updated question, but that "success" property should work if you set it up like this:

```
   success: $.proxy(that.dogSaved, that),
```

The first argument to `$.proxy()` is the function to be called, and the second is the value you want for `this` when the function is called. In this case, you want it to be the saved reference to the dog object. Note, however, that it will only work if the "save" function is called with `this` set to a dog.  That is, if somewhere you do this:

```
   var fido = new Dog();
   fido.save();
```

then things should work.  However, if you somehow use that "save" function in some way such that `this` is not a reference to a dog, then it won't work.  Again, if in the "Dog" constructor you were to move that declaration of "that" out to the constructor scope instead of in "save", then it won't matter how "save" is called because "that" will *always* be a reference to the dog object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still completely lost! I didn't mean to use a click handler in the dog example. Thanks

Comment: @Jodes well you *did* use a "click" handler.  It's pretty important on Stackoverflow to make sure that the sample code you post accurately reflects the problem you're having, because it's your code that we'll focus on to provide assistance.